# Получить метод loadDomain для gmail из настроек расширения

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Ищу в в документации и примерах как можно на странице gmail получить данные из настроек нашего расширения. Но что то совсем никак не могу понять, как это реализуется.

На самой странице настроек есть метод **loadDomain()** который получает ранее сохранённые данные в переменную **localStorage**

В скрипте который я встраиваю в gmail **main.js** я не знаю как мне получить данный метод  **loadDomain()**  с массивом который мы сохраняли из настроек расширения.
Сам **manifest.json** выглядит следующим образом:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://mail.google.com/*", "http://*/*, https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "38": "icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "SalesUp",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
    "js/gmail.js",
    "main.js"
  ]
}
```

Метод **loadDomain()** находится в скрипте который подключается через options.html